# Is there anyway to find only A character and replace with another character in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

For e.g.

If lots of address are given like below

```
house no. 123, sector A, dr. RAMESH, uttar pradesh
house no. 456, A, sector B NARESH , UTTAR PRADESH
```

in the above two lines i want to find only A letter not in RAMESH and NARESH just only A letter in excel ? is it possible to find only A character ?
Please write if there is anyway to find only A character ?

Comment: Something like `=MATCH("*"&", A,"&"*",A:A,0)` or using SEARCH?

Comment: =find("*A*",A1,1) and drag down.

Comment: Some examples (to replace " A," with " B,") are: first occurrence - `=REPLACE(A1,FIND(" A,",A1)+1,1,"B")`, all occurrences - `=SUBSTITUTE(A1," A,"," B,")`.

Answer (score 0):

The common part of that string is the "A" is prefixed by a space and suffixed by a comma.  Therefore, this will work for the example you provided.

```
=FIND(" A,",A1)
```

Naturally, that's if the value is in cell A1.

[image]